# How to break out of Object.map() - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get `map` to stop when `if` finds the first `isOccupied`

```
Object.keys(this.props.parkingLot).map((slot) => {
    if (!this.props.parkingLot[slot].isOccupied) {
        newSlotNo = slot;
        this.props.addCar(newSlotNo, this.state.newCarRegNo, this.state.newCarColor);
        console.log(this.slot)
    }
})
```

Comment: What do you mean *get map to stop*? The function converts an array to an array of the same length. Contrary to [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (that you should check out!), it does not really mean anything for `.map` to "stop"

Comment: what i mean to say is, I want to access the first `slot` only which is not occupied and then exit out of the `map` function

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
if (!this.props.parkingLot[slot].isOccupied && newSlotNo == 0)
```

once `newSlotNo` is set to `slot` it won't be 0 anymore, hence `if` will not execute breaking the `map` function.

Thank you people for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `parkingLot` is an array of objects and you're only interested in the index of the array where there is an object with property `isOccupied === true`:

```
const parkingLot = [
  {isOccupied: false}, // index 0
  {isOccupied: false}, // index 1
  {isOccupied: true}   // index 2
];
```

You can find the *first* `index`/`slot` of the  array that is occupied by:

```
parkingLot.findIndex(parkingSpot => parkingSpot.isOccupied); // returns 2
```

You could also [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) the `isOccupied` property

```
parkingLot.findIndex(({isOccupied}) => isOccupied); // returns 2
```

**Note:** [`Array.prototype.findIndex()` isn't compatible with Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Browser_compatibility). If you have to support IE you could add [the `findIndex()` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill) to your codebase or reach for the equivalent function in a data operation utility library like Lodash or Ramda.

- [Ramda's `findIndex()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#findIndex)
- [Lodash's `findIndex()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#findIndex)